# conditional instantiation of template class

Tags: c++11, templates, std

I have a class `MyClass<size_t, type>`.
I would like to add conditional template instantiation using `std::is_same` and `std::conditional`.

However, both types for the first parameter are the same and are `size_t`.
As expected when `MYSIZE1` and `MYSIZE2` are the same, `class<MYSIZE,int>`   will give an error.

How can I perform this conditional compilation considering that the only change is in the value of the template parameter?

```
template class MyClass<
                   std::conditional< (!std::is_same<MyClass<MYSIZE1,int>,
                                                    MyClass<MYSIZE2,int> 
                                                  >::value),
                                     MyClass<DUMMYSIZE,int>, 
                                     Myclass<MYSIZE1,  int>
                                   >::type,
                   int>;
```

This does not work obviously as conditional returns MyClass type.

Comment: What you want to achieve? For me that reads like an XY problem! And "This does not work obviously as conditional returns MyClass type.": conditional returns a MyClass<x,y> and not MyClass or have I something missed.

Comment: I try to prevent duplicate template instantiation error when the user specifies two parameters as identical

Comment: Having two times the same template instance is not an error! I can't catch your point.

Comment: It is an error : "error: duplicate explicit instantiation of ‘class MyClass<10, double>"

Comment: You did not have 2 instances, you have two *explicit* instances. We did not see the code you use so it is not easy to help. As you see: No answers after hours! You should clarify your question with a minimal compilable example!

Comment: The code is very big  I can not post it here, as you can see, user inputs two parameters, and for each of those the template is explicitly instantiated, once he enters same values for both variables, it gets instantiated twice, MyClass<DUMMYSIZE1,int> and MyClass<DUMMYSIZE2,int> are at the end of the template class instantiating the class,